# Select Box on change Not called for this Function

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-selectors

```
$('input[id*=id_]').bind('change',function(){
var num= $(this).parent().parent().children().first().html()*1;
callfunc2(num);
});
  function callFunc2(num){
    if(num)>1{
      if ($('#id_select'+num).val()=='' &&
      $('#id_text1'+num).val()=='' && 
      $('#id_text2'+num).val()==''){
      validatenone();
     }else{
     vaidateall();
   }}}

So My Problem is Iam not able to call the Callfunc2()
```

when i change or select another item in the Selectbox other than the default value.Now my Select box has an id of "id_select" prrefixed.And it is calling callfunc2() for textbox but not select bo what might be the reason

Comment: I think you're going to need to supply some additional code, or even a test case would be nice - there is a lot of events firing going on that is not demonstrated above.

Comment: Your braces aren't correct, `if(num)>1{` should be `if(num>1){`

Comment: @Nick:I tried That One Also .it is calling the function  when we change the textbox value but not for Select box

Comment: @Someone - Your selector doesn't cover `<select>` elements, only `<input>` elements.

Comment: @Nick:How do i change the Selector so that it covers Select Elements also?

Comment: @Someone - `$('input[id*=id_], select[id*=id_]')` for example

Comment: @Nick:Thank you That Solved it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your selector won't find `<select>` elements, you need to add those in there, like this:

```
$('input[id*=id_], select[id*=id_]').change(function(){
  var num= +$(this).parent().parent().children().first().html();
  callfunc2(num);
});
```

There are other syntax issues as well, `if(num)>1{` should be `if(num>1){`, but the above selector issue is why it's not getting called at all.